# Get Maximum Value With Condition in CSV

Tags: python

Find the maximum amount of rainfall on days where the maximum temperature was above 25 degrees Celsius.

climate_data_2017.csv

```
Date,Minimum temperature (C),Maximum temperature (C),Rainfall (mm),Evaporation (mm),Sunshine (hours),Direction of maximum wind gust,Speed of maximum wind gust (km/h),9am Temperature (C),9am relative humidity (%),3pm Temperature (C),3pm relative humidity (%)
2017-01-01,22.7,26.6,0,6.8,0,E,24,24.6,70,24.9,70
2017-01-02,21.2,26.3,0.4,3.4,3.5,S,56,22.1,71,24.8,54
2017-01-03,18.5,26.6,2.6,6.2,8.8,SSE,48,21.9,66,25.4,60
2017-01-04,20.1,25.9,1.2,7.8,5.6,ESE,31,24,53,23.7,45
2017-01-05,19.6,24.3,5,6,0.5,ENE,30,20.5,89,22.6,69
2017-01-06,19.9,26.5,8.8,3.8,4.8,E,35,20,86,25.3,57
2017-01-07,19.2,26.8,4.4,6.6,11.5,NE,43,24.8,61,25.2,57
```

My Code is below:

```
rainfall = 0
count = 0
is_first_line = True

for row in open("climate_data_2017.csv"):
  if is_first_line:
    is_first_line = False
  else:
    values = row.split(",")
    temp = float(values[2])
    if temp > 25:
      rainfall = max(values[3])

print("Maximum amount of rainfall on hot days: ", rainfall)
```

Expected output:

```
Maximum amount of rainfall on hot days:  8.8
```

Current output:

```
Maximum amount of rainfall on hot days:  4
```

Comment: Why not use Pandas?

Comment: Or why not use SQLite in memory?

Comment: You can also use numpy's `argmax()`

Comment: Let me try argmax(). I have not try to use SQLite on this yet. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because when you do `rainfall = max(values[3])` you don't get a list of `values[3]`, you only get `values[3]` for that row. This should work:

```
rainfall = 0
count = 0
is_first_line = True
above25 = []

for row in open("climate_data_2017.csv"):
  if is_first_line:
    is_first_line = False
  else:
    values = row.split(",")
    temp = float(values[2])
    if temp > 25:
        above25.append(values[3])

rainfall = max(above25)

print("Maximum amount of rainfall on hot days: ", rainfall)
```

Comment: Good answer. It would be worthy of upvotes if you could explain the reason why you have done this way. Stackoverflow is a community, and there will be someone in the future who would look at this answer.

Comment: I just updated my answer then saw your comment.

Comment: This solution works, thanks for your explanation!